# React / Web3: different behavior in componendDidMount and Function

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I'm building a React.js application with Web3.js to connect to MetaMask in the browser.

Below function provides exactly the desired outcome -> it triggers MetaMask to open and I connect to the wallet.

Code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let adr = null;

    try {
        adr = await this.state.web3.eth.requestAccounts();

        this.setState({
            address: adr[0]
        });
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.code === 4001) {
            // EIP-1193 userRejectedRequest error
            // If this happens, the user rejected the connection request.
            console.log('Please connect to wallet.');
        } else {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    }
}
```

The function below has the same code but instead of automatically being called when the React component is mounted it gets triggered by the click of a button. Unfortunately, the outcome is the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
at loginWithEth (WalletAuth.js:52)
```

Code:

```
async loginWithEth() {
    let adr = null;

    try {
        adr = await this.state.web3.eth.requestAccounts(); //that's line 52 where the errors is thrown

        this.setState({
            address: adr[0]
        });
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.code === 4001) {
            // EIP-1193 userRejectedRequest error
            // If this happens, the user rejected the connection request.
            console.log('Please connect to wallet.');
        } else {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you bind the `loginWithEth` method in the class? As per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) 
`You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.`

Comment: You would have to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the onClick to the component  I guess, but this is some old looking react, today you should be doing these things with functions and useState / useEffect

Answer (score 0):

Missed to bind `loginWithEth` in the class!

```
this.loginWithEth = this.loginWithEth.bind(this);
```

Thanks, Junaid and pguardiario.